# Can a favicon at the root path be in a different image format than ICO?

Tags: images, favicon

Most clients use the favicon if it is named `favicon.ico` and placed in the root path of a website.

Is it possible to use an image format other than `.ico`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that by default the browser only checks the `/favicon.ico` path, however we can use an HTML meta tag to tell it explicitly where the favicon is if it's at a different path or in a different image format than `.ico`.

In addition to `.ico`, you can use the `.gif` and `.png` file formats [in all modern browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support) as long as you [use an HTML meta tag on your page to specify their path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Standardization):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="image/favicon.png">
```

There are some other file formats that can be used for favicons, but only `.ico`, `.gif` and `.png` are widely supported.

---

To address your comment, the `/favicon.ico` path is the only path that browsers will check without being prompted by an HTML meta tag. If you want to serve up a favicon of a different file type without using an HTML meta tag, you can always 30X-redirect the `/favicon.ico` path to the path of a `.png` or `.gif` file.

Comment: My question was not about icons mentioned in html tags.

Comment: If you want to use a different format, you can mention it in an HTML tag.  Then what you mention will be used instead of the default `.ico` format

Comment: @buhtz Just addressed this in my edit.

Comment: I redirect favicon.ico to favicon.png and that seems to work.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller My gut says that that solution wouldn't be best practice, as I imagine even after the redirect, the browser is still expecting a `.ico`-formatted image. I would guess that the reason it works is that most browsers are coded to gracefully accept an unexpected file format. But now I am not sure about that at all, I could easily be wrong. I would be curious if there are any sources saying that the redirect setup is good practice or standards compliant - I did a cursory search and couldn't find anything.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I think you are right - i.e. a redirect is fine. According to [this source](https://bitsofco.de/all-about-favicons-and-touch-icons/) the W3C says that in the case of the `link` HTML meta tag, the `type` attribute is considered "non-authoritative", which tells me that there probably isn't any special file-type trickery here. The client just reads the MIME type from the `content-type` header from the server, like with any other resource. I included this info in my answer. Thanks!